# Distributed reading from replica sets in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, replication

I can read from master in replica set. It's easy. But does everyone know, how read from secondary in replica pair? It very efficient for scaling, but i didn't search anything about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here are the docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying#Querying-slaveOk) you're looking for.

You'll need to dig in to your specific driver for how to do this.